# Magento - maximum price more than 100 million

Tags: php, mysql, magento

I work with magento and I need to use prices more than 100.000.000 , in other words , more than decimal(12,4).

As a result of my researches, I have to change every database field that is related to price. Now I have two questions :

1- Does anyone know which tables or fields should be concerned in this case ?

2- Is there any other way to increase price maximum amount ?

Comment: wouldn't it be easier to store only a fraction of the amount in the database and when you echo it you multiply it, eg. store `1.25` in db and echo `1.25 * 1,000,000 = 1,250,000`

Comment: It would be a good solution, but I need all digits in calculation, So I can't omit them. for example, I have some digits like 130,432,123.23 . So the solution does not fit in this case. btw thanks a lot :)

Answer (score 1):

These Columns/Tables :

- value column in table: `catalog_product_entity_decimal`,
- price column in table:`catalog_product_index_price`,
- price column in table:`catalog_product_index_price_tmp`,
- price column in table:`catalog_product_index_price_final_tmp`,